# Rough but correct way to determine CPU load for a thread?

Tags: multithreading, timer, cpu

I would like to know if I have the concept correct - say I want to find out the CPU utilization of a thread running in a multithreaded application. There's an infinite while loop running in the thread of interest that does all the processing required. I have a variable that tracks the time spent in this loop.

I run the code and set a breakpoint at the loop. I start an external stopwatch and run the code from the start of the while loop, simultaneously (as much as I can). I pause the code and stop the stopwatch at the same time.

Now CPU utilization by this thread is time spent in this thread/total time passed?

Is the concept correct at all? Except for the rough nature of these estimates and the human error involved in starting the code and stopping it and the stopwatch exactly at the same time.

Comment: Seems what you get is always 100%. If there is only on thread running, then this calculation makes sense. But if there are other threading running simultaneously, then between the start_time and end_time you record, there will be some time slices when the thread is scheduled out, waiting for CPU to execute, so your calculation does not make sense. Linux kernel uses a counter to do this, you can refer to that.

Comment: Won't the calculation make more sense if there are multiple threads running? The time counter will only measure the time in which the thread of interest is actually running, and stops when it is scheduled out.

Comment: Actually, a thread itself can not know whether it is scheduled in or out. Only the OS can take care of it.